# Remove scrollbar when nothing to scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

I want to have a scrollbar when they are items, but when there is nothing to scroll to don't appear the scrollbar.

[image]

If I use this, it removes it, but in all cases. I want to see the scrollbar if it's not empty:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: inline;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to hide the main browser scroll bar or just any block(div) scrollbar?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Any block(div). I want to hide the scrollbar if there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The component was added with this css style `overflow-y: scroll;` and I changed to `overflow-y: auto;`.

So now if there is no elements to scroll doesn't appear the scrollbar.